# Why does writing an image to a stream give me a different result than directly saving to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, drawing

I am trying to add some rectangles to an existing image. When using the following code, everything works fine:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("myPath\\input.jpg");
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

using (var i = new Bitmap(stream))
{
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(i))
    {
        var selPen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(selPen, 10, 10, 50, 50);

        i.Save("myPath\\output.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

But saving the image to the same MemoryStream and then later writing all bytes to a file gives me an almost grey-only image.

This does not work:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("myPath\\input.jpg");
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

using (var i = new Bitmap(stream))
{
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(i))
    {
        var selPen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(selPen, 10, 10, 50, 50);

        i.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}

File.WriteAllBytes("myPath\\output.jpg", stream.ToArray());
```

The (wrong) image looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, only part of the image is grey. There still is some part visible (the white one) of the actual image.

Why is this happening and what is the correct solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've double-written to the `Stream` in the second example; it still contains the *original* data, and then you've **appended** more data with the `Save`. `Stream` works like a video tape (sort of). If you want to overwrite the stream, you need to do that very carefully (and: not all streams even support that concept - think "network stream", "encryption stream", etc). Note that `ToArray` (and the `GetBuffer` / `TryGetBuffer` methods) see *all* the data, not just what you're thinking of as the "new" data (a concept that doesn't even exist, really - like a video tape, you only have the "current" position and the length - if you need to know where the first show ends and the second show starts, you need to note that yourself, manually). In this case, adding:

```
stream.Position = 0; // rewind
stream.SetLength(0); // truncate (important in case the new data is *shorter* than the old)
```

after reading it and before `Save`, should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You  are saving the image to an already initialized stream from a byte array.

Create a new  stream and save to it.

```
 var stream2 = new MemoryStream();
 i.Save(stream2, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Or simply reset the previous one

```
 memoryStream = new MemoryStream(stream.Capacity());
```

Comment: the code in the edit does not "reset the previous one" - it absolutely creates a new stream; the only thing that is retained is the *local variable*